# Why cant I center this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is killing me. https://leadcheetah.com/dummy.php - Not sure why I can't center the input box and submit button. I've tried using bootstrap columns and manually adding align="center"

```
<div class="search-container" style="transform: translateY(0px);">

                <!-- Form -->
                <h2 align="center">Search Finder Tool</h2>
                <form method="POST" action="email-extract/email-extractor-service.php" id="findemail">
                <input type="text" align="center" name="domain" id="domain" class="ico-01" placeholder="i.e. cnn.com" value=""><br><br><br>
        <p><input type="submit" class="button" value="Find Emails"></p>
                </form>

                <!-- Browse Jobs
                <div class="browse-jobs">
                    Browse job offers by <a href="browse-categories.html"> category</a> or <a href="#">location</a>
                </div> -->


            </div>
```

Comment: Your URL is strange, btw...don't use `align="center"` on input. Use CSS instead, something like `style="margin: 0 auto;"`

Comment: Check answer may be it will help you.

Comment: Fun fact: the `align` attribute in an input used to align the text inside, in Opera v12 and lower.

Comment: @MrLister Cool! I really need to learn CSS properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.search-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container">

  <!-- Form -->
  <h2 align="center">Search Finder Tool</h2>
  <form method="POST" action="email-extract/email-extractor-service.php" id="findemail">
    <input type="text" align="center" name="domain" id="domain" class="ico-01" placeholder="i.e. cnn.com" value=""><br><br><br>
    <p><input type="submit" class="button" value="Find Emails"></p>
  </form>

  <!-- Browse Jobs
                <div class="browse-jobs">
                    Browse job offers by <a href="browse-categories.html"> category</a> or <a href="#">location</a>
                </div> -->


</div>
```

**[fiddle link with bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/Lokeshg27/tp53tv82/6/)**

Button out from `form` and `input` and `button` inline center. I added a parent div for `form` and `button` so please check `html` also.

**[Edit as your requirement](https://jsfiddle.net/Lokeshg27/tp53tv82/7/)**

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer; I tried to implement it but the find button is now stuck next to it. I tried to take it out of the form but it looks like its stuck do you have any thoughts

Comment: If you take out from form it will align next to input but next line  center

Comment: I really appreciate your responses..Here is your code implemented - https://leadcheetah.com/dummytemp.php. The find button is next to it.

Comment: So it will works as your requirement ? check answer i posted one more fiddle as your requirement.

Comment: Ah! I made one more alteration and it worked; I removed width = 44% on the .search-container input. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without the use of Flexbox (as it's not supported in many browsers)

Your markup should look similar to the following

```
<form method="POST" action="email-extract/email-extractor-service.php" id="findemail" style="width: 100%;text-align: center;margin: auto;">
    <input type="text" align="center" name="domain" id="domain" class="ico-01" placeholder="i.e. cnn.com" value="">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Find Emails">
</form>
```

Adjusted styles

```
#findemail {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Remove the `float:left` and `margin-right: 2%` from `.search-container input` and add `margin: auto;` to it.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4r6e.png)

Edit: Also, make sure to remove the `<br>` tags.

Comment: Flexbox is supported in all browsers except for those that were not very happy with CSS rules in the first place. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Unfortunately, for general consumer-facing websites (unlike web applications) you will likely need to offer support for IE11/10. Flexbox offers only partial support for those browsers. While using Flexbox for small things (not layout) is probably fine, I wouldn't recommend it for centering a prominent element such as a search box that is displayed above the fold. It's completely unnecessary with proper markup and styles.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response; I made the changes you stated but its still not centering; I also added a bunch of breaks just to see what would happen and it still aligns left

Comment: @UsmanShahid it looks like you took down the example web page, it now displays a 404 page. Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @MitchGlenn - thanks for the response. I was with Lokesh's answer. I took down the page (it was only a placeholder) - your answer wasn't displaying properly (Im sure it was something I was doing) ...I really apprecaite your response!

Answer (score 0):

On all components that you wish to center, ensure there are the following styles and that they are not being over-ridden.

```
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

Also noticed that there is a 
    float:left; 
that will have to be removed from the CSS.

Hope it helps.